# What are the different EBCDIC code pages for traditional chinese?

Tags: oracle, encoding, chinese-locale, ebcdic

All I know is code page 937 for EBCDIC traditional chinese.
[CP937](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/ccsid/ccsid937.html)

The reason that I am asking is that I have an EBCDIC file that contains traditional chinese characters but have boxes and question marks when I load them to Oracle using ZHT16DBCS (code page 937) character set.

Additional note:
I can't process the file because it's in EBCDIC and contains traditional chinese characters. I would like to convert it to UTF-8 so I can read using my script (Perl) and extract to several files and load the files to several DB tables.

Comment: How do you load this file into DB?

Comment: I load this using sqlldr and a control file but I set characterset first.

load CHARACTER SET ZHT16DBCS

Comment: Are you sure your file is encoded as CP937? Where did you get the information that Oracle Character set `ZHT16DBCS` matches IBM codepage CP937?

Comment: Thanks. I added a response to your post below following this link where I got it.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b16217/a_nls.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether IBM codepage `CP937` matches Oracle character set `ZHT16DBCS`, resp. if Oracle support CP937 at all.

My recommendation would be to make a conversion to a more common character set, e.g. UTF-8. You can use for example [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html) which is part of Java SE.

Would be like this:

```
native2ascii your_input_file native_file.txt -encoding x-IBM937    
native2ascii native_file.txt your_input_file_in_utf8 -reverse -encoding UTF-8
```

or using pipe to make it in one step:

```
cat your_input_file | native2ascii -encoding x-IBM937 | native2ascii -reverse -encoding UTF-8 > your_input_file_in_utf8
```

Then, before you run sqlldr set `NLS_LANG` accordingly:

```
SET NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8 (Windows)

export NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8 (Unix)
```

Just a note, territory and language are not relevant, so you can skip them if you like (as I did).

Of course, in your control file must you must set

```
CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
```

Another note, "UTF-8" encoding means Oracle character set "AL32UTF8". There is also a Oracle character set named "UTF8", however this is [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8). For European languages they can be considered as equal, however for Chinese they might be different.

Comment: Thanks but I got it from oracle docs when I was searching for character sets with EBCDIC and traditional chinese.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b16217/a_nls.htm
#M   937 = ZHT16DBCS shift # Traditional Chinese multi-byte              EBCDIC

Comment: That's when I tried ZHT16DBCS and assumed it was 937

Comment: Yes, I also found this document but do you have an IBM DRDA server? I don't know whether "Oracle Transparent Gateway for DRDA" applies also to "SQL*Loader" - I don't think so.

Comment: No I don't think we have. Could you please explain why I need to know about oracle DRDA server and its purpose?

Comment: I have noted your suggestion using Java SE to convert the file to utf8 but sad to say that don't have Java installed in AIX 6.1. Will have install manually.